# How can I make this question not opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, good-questions

First of all, I'm very comfortable with the fact that the answer to this question may be "there isn't a way", but if it all possible I'd like to reword my question so that it can be answered in a way that is useful to other users as well.

The question is this: [As a Canadian, what are appropriate gifts to bring when travelling to Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78016/as-a-canadian-what-are-appropriate-gifts-to-bring-when-travelling-to-europe)

If I reword this to something like "What are some uniquely Canadian souvenirs?" is that better, or is that still opinion-based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Q has been reopened so I suggest what you have already done is all that is required.